# Redirect stdout to file descriptor does not seems to work, why?

Tags: c, linux, file, redirect, stdout

I tested this:

```
#include<unistd.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
int main()
{
    int fd=open("./testdup.txt",O_CREAT|O_RDWR,0666);
    dup2(STDOUT_FILENO,fd);
    write(STDOUT_FILENO,"mymy\n",5);
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

compile and run it, it stills prints

```
mymy
```

Not as I expected: the write operation should write to "testdup.txt" file.
Why it didn't work?

Comment: Why are you not checking any error conditions?

Comment: If `fd` is already in use, then `dup2(x, fd)` closes fd first, then makes fd a copy of x.  That's not what you want.

Comment: swap the arguments in dup2:  dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@TobyB is correct here. This code works for me:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(void)
{
    int fd = open("./testdup.txt", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);
    dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, "mymy\n", 5);
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

The order of the arguments to dup2 were incorrect in your program.